# Inaccuracies identifying a marker inside a polygon using Google Maps and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, geospatial

I have drawn a polygon on a Google Map

```
new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [
        { lat: 52.474617867242515, lng: -1.8111903062499923 },
        { lat: 51.527748727453975, lng: -2.7340418687499923 },
        { lat: 51.41825758811742, lng: -0.40494030624999233 },
    ],
    fillColor: '#FFC107',
}).setMap(map);
```

I can also click to place new markers on the map, passing the coordinates to the server and then displaying a coloured marker: green if inside the polygon, red if outside.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', (e) => {
    axios.post('/home/testmarker', e.overlay.getPosition()).then((response) => {
        e.overlay.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + response.data + '-dot.png');
    });
});
```

On my server, I check if the new marker falls inside my polygon. There will eventually be lots of polygons to check, for now I have hardcoded a copy of the polygon inside a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestMarker]
    @lat varchar(20),
    @lng varchar(20)
AS

DECLARE @g geography;  
DECLARE @h geography;  
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-1.8111903062499923 52.474617867242515, -2.7340418687499923 51.527748727453975, -0.40494030624999233 51.41825758811742, -1.8111903062499923 52.474617867242515))', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @lng + ' ' + @lat + ')', 4326);

SELECT @g.STContains(@h);
```

Around the corners, my markers are accurately identified as being inside or outside the polygon.

[image: Corner Markers]

However, the sides are a different story. Picking a point halfway along each side and the markers are no longer being accurately identified as inside or outside the polygon.

[image: Sides using Geography]

I have also tried using the geometry data type, so my SP looks like

```
...
DECLARE @g geometry;  
DECLARE @h geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-1.8111903062499923 52.474617867242515, -2.7340418687499923 51.527748727453975, -0.40494030624999233 51.41825758811742, -1.8111903062499923 52.474617867242515))', 0);
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + @lng + ' ' + @lat + ')', 0);
...
```

**Note, I have changed the SRID to 0**

The corners remain as accurate as before, but the accuracy along the sides has changed, significantly so along the bottom edge

[image: Sides using Geometry]

*In the first and third images, the top row of markers are the previous ones identified using 'geography', the bottom rows are the new ones calculated using 'geometry'.*

Does anyone know what needs to be done to fix this?

I have a suspicion this is somehow related to SRID with Geography, and the method Google Maps are using. In my first example, I was using 4326 which seems to be widely recommended. [I found that Google should be using this as well](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST80JvGJI1xoZk/?hl=en-GB), although they also use something called 3857, I don't seem to have that in SQL Server - at least not by default. I have no previously-stored data so I can easily change the way I both store and compare data if needed to make this work.

Comment: Haven't checked your code but could you not do that on the front-end with the geometry library and [`containsLocation` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.containsLocation)?

Comment: And looose all the functions including geospatial indexing on the backend?

Comment: @TomTom he's using an API on the front-end to apparently create or render both the markers and the polygons and that same API has a method to check whether a point lies within a Polygon (which seems to be what OP is trying to do). What does this have to do with loosing anything on the backend?

Comment: @MrUpsidown the ultimate goal is something similar to a store locator, so a single point will be passed in (eg postcode) which could be compared against a large number of possible polygons to find records that 'cover' that single point. I don't think it'll be feasible to pass all that data back just so the browser can work it out.

Comment: It looks like in your testing you're jamming a bunch of points to see where it goes sideways. For the false negatives, what does `@g.STDistance(@h)` give?

Comment: @Chris in that case no, you better process it server side.

Comment: I read from the SQL [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geography-instances?view=sql-server-ver15) that *SQL Server uses the default SRID of 4326, which maps to the WGS 84 spatial reference system, when using methods on geography instances*. Google Maps API [uses WGS 84](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates). Is it possible that you need to render your Polygons with [`geodesic`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon?hl=en#PolygonOptions) set to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

> and the markers are no longer being accurately identified as inside or
>   outside the polygon

...slightly buffering the polygon?

```
DECLARE @g geometry = 'POLYGON((1 1, 1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1))'; 
SELECT @g.STBuffer(0.1).STDifference(@g);
```

> they also use something called 3857

```
declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1))', 3857)
select @g, @g.STSrid


declare @g geometry = 'POLYGON((1 1, 1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1))', @p geometry = 'POINT(0.9999999 2.1)';
select @g.STDistance(@p), case when @g.STDistance(@p) <= 0.000001 then 1 else 0 end as tolerancecontainsYN, @g.STIntersects(@p) as intersectsYN, @g.STContains(@p) as containsYN
```

Comment: I don't think a viable solution as I seem to have inconsistencies with sometimes the markers being detected outside the polygon (when they shouldn't be) and other times vice versa. A fixed buffer would just lead to more incorrect matches outside the polygon, or if I did a negative buffer I could potentially miss even more from inside the polygon.

Comment: maybe some tolerance using distance instead of contains/intersects?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is discrepancy between spherical model of `GEOGRAPHY` type and planar model of Google Maps. You use `GEOGRAPHY` type in SQLServer, which is spherical. It only supports SRID `4326`. `GEOGRAPHY` also uses geodesic edges - the line between A and B follows the shortest path on the **globe**, not the straight line on the **map**.

First of all you should decide what semantics you really want here?

If you do want a polygon with geodesic edges, you should keep `GEOGRAPHY` but use the geodesic edges in Google Maps as well. Just add `geodesic: true` to Polygon arguments. The edges of your polygon will look slightly curved but will mostly match SQLServer boundary. I think there might still be minor discrepancy due to ellipsoidal vs. sphere computation in SQLServer and Google Maps.

If you do want a polygon with edges that look straight on a map, you don't need geography type, but should use `GEOMETRY` SQLServer type. This should give you access to various SRID and planar edges on map, but I'm not sure what to use to make them match Google Maps.